# Usage of % in function and method names

Tags: naming-conventions, common-lisp, naming, conventions

I'm looking through code and seeing `%` at the beginning of function and method names. For example `defun %rod` and `defmethod %do-query`. Is there a standard convention for using this kind of naming scheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a [few](http://www.cliki.net/naming%20conventions) [places](http://community.schemewiki.org/?variable-naming-convention):

> %foo: low-level, fast, dangerous function, or Lisp system specific implementation of foo

Answer (score 4):

For naming conventions in Common Lisp see here:

http://www.cliki.net/naming%20conventions